# Initialize a byte array to a certain value

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

I want to find  an answer for one simple question.

Say we defined a byte array called : x_parms.
If I want to make sure that the value in the array is 0, should I do this:

```
x_parms = new byte[1];
```

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by _If I want to make value `0`_ exactly? Do you wanna get byte array with one item which value is `0`? If so, that's correct.

Comment: @ Soner Gönül ensure that I zero the value

Comment: @TinMat: since `default(byte)` is  0 it is ensured.

Comment: Yes, since `byte` is a value type, all elements in array are initialized with their default values which is `0`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  I'm just little confused why we don't do like this :x_parms = new byte[0];  ?

Comment: @TinMat: Because that would create an empty array. The number in the square brackets is the *length* of the array, not the initial element value.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the length of the x_params :

```
x_parms = new byte[21];
```

or

```
x_parms = new byte[36];
```

system will allocate 21 or 36 byte that have 0 as default !

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
x_parms = new byte[1];
```

The `1` means you have an array of length 1.

To set the value to 0, you would use something like

```
x_params[0] = 0;
```

Where the first `0` says "set the value in index position 0" and the second `0` means "set the value to be 0".

As others have mentioned in the comment, the default value of `byte` is 0, so setting it explicitly is not necessary.

For more information, consult https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx.  In particular,

```
The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero
```

and

```
Arrays are zero indexed: an array with n elements is indexed from 0 to n-1
```

In the section titled Array Overview

Comment: Setting the value to 0 is unnecessary for non-nullable bytes.  Their default value will be populated and that is 0.

Comment: yes, that's why the answer includes this line:

"As others have mentioned in the comment, the default value of byte is 0, so setting it explicitly is not necessary."

Comment: i see.  I missed it somehow.